# how to provide default value from function that return type is unknown in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have one customizedHook that returns type is `typeXYZ || unknown`. and I would like to de-structure the returned value but I have the error `TS2339: Property 'xyz' does not exist on type 'unknown'.` even the data return as xyz: {}, and abc returns ['string1', 'string2']
How can I solve it?

```
export function useAPICall(): typeXYZ || unknown {
  const {data} = useQuery(['apiCallData'], async () => {
    const value: typeABC = (await cbFunction()) as typeABC;
    return value?.defaultValue;
  });



  return {data};
//console.log(data)
//{xyz: {abc: 'asdasda', cde: 'xzczxc'}, abc: ['aaaa','bbbb','cccc']}

}

const {xyz: {}, abc: string[]} = useAPICall()
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/we0rEW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a union type like `TypeXYZ | unknown` (it's a single pipe), the type restrictions become *stricter* than any of the individual types in the union, contrary to what you might imagine.

For example, if you have this code:

```
   const a = get_value() as number | string;
   const b = parseInt(a, 10);
```

you'll get a type error because parseInt does not allow a number type argument. In other words, any code you write using the union has to be valid for *all* types in the union. Because `unknown` is the most restrictive type of all (you usually have to cast it to something to use it), it effectively completely overrides XYZ.

However, if you used `any`, the least restrictive type, then there would be no point in having `TypeXYZ` at all, since `any` would allow you to do anything with the object.

If you are destructuring xyz, then you must (or should!) know the object is of type TypeXYZ before you do that, in which case you can cast it using `as TypeXYZ`.

Remember Typescript knows nothing about your runtime types, and if your API returns something unexpected, that's a situation Typescript cannot help you with. So if your API returns data that may take multiple forms, you need to do some runtime type-checking, something like:

```
 const res = useApiCall();
 if (res.xyz) {
   const { xyz } = res as TypeXYZ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide default values to a unknown type like this:

```js
const defaults: { abc: string, def: number} = { abc: "somedefaultval", def: 123 }
const someUnknown: unknown = { abc: "abc" }

const result: { abc: string, def: number} = { ...defaults, ...someUnknown }
// result is { abc: "abc", def: 123 }
```